# Halal or haram marriage

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, sunnah, husband-wife

Salamalaikum!
My question is regarding my marriage
When I met my husband I wasnt paying much attention to the religion so we married in court as civil marriage. My father and mother left me alone in another country so I didn't have any wali present during the day we got married. Now that I am concerned and learn more about Islam i would like to know in my case is our marriage valid. 
Jazakkallahkhair.

Comment: what do you mean by a "Civil Marriage"? And if the Nikah ceremony was sermonized according to Islamic law, then there is no need for your parents to be present in your marriage if you are already an adult and reached the puberty.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Islam SE is not a fatwa site (see [ask]). You should consider consulting a _mufti_ in your area. Questions of this nature will most likely be closed. Please refer to [ask], and take a [tour] in our [help].

Comment: @III-AK-III if she replaces "i" to "some woman", does not it became non fatwa question?

Comment: @qdinar — There is an ongoing discussion on [meta] about the topic if you care to participate. In my opinion, it remains a fatwa question, but I am not the single voting authority in this community. Anyone who feels confident enough to give a response that they can defend on the Day of Judgment may answer the question.

Comment: This question leaves many points open: I suppose you are a Muslim, how about your husband? -you haven't mentioned his faith! It is strange for Muslims to seek civil marriage -only-. As mentioned above this question rather needs a fatwa, even if my impression from many fatwas, is that scholars rarely tend to separate a couple even if their marriage is invalid by shar'ia, but for details this really needs a fatwa.